# Windows 8 search can't find folder

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-search

How to force the windows SEARCH to **FIND ALL FOLDERS**, containing "test" part?
This is demonstration, how it is **not working**:

**8 folders**

[image]

**only 7 folders**

[image]

What is wrong or how to correctly input the search words? Or I have to reconfigure something?

This is "C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder (2)" And search is inside only this folder.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to happen? Looking of the screenshot, everything works as expected, so I think what you want requires some additional steps. For that to tell you, we obviously need to understand what result you expect to see (be as detailed as possible). Please edit your post and include this information.

Comment: It looks like its working.  What exactly is wrong about those search results?

Comment: This might be really useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Ramhound, he wrote "This is demonstration, how it is NOT working" :)

Comment: @LinusWaerner - Right.  Except it is working.  His screenshot is finding all folders with names that contain the word "test" in them.  The question isn't clear at this point and thus is not helpful and is essentially unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: @Ramhound, I just noticed. My bad. It matter what folder he begins the search from, right? I mean, to find all folders he must have to be searching from C:/

Comment: @LinusWaerner -  Why are you asking me?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. It was a question of my own. Anyway, that might be the issue: @XuMuK, are you searching from "This computer", or in "C:/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved adding  asterisk "*":

[image]